# How to compute rolling rank correlation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compute rolling rank correlation between two columns in a data frame. However, the current `rolling_corr` in pandas does not support rank correlation. I tried to implement rolling rank correlation with `rolling_apply`, but did not have any success. It seems like `rolling_apply` only takes one array as input argument, but correlation needs two arrays. Is there a clever way to implement rolling rank correlation with `rolling_apply` or some other methods? Rank correlation would be a nice addition to `rolling_corr` if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `rolling_apply` can be used to do a rolling correlation, as it seems to break DataFrames into 1-d arrays. There may be better ways to do this, but one solution is to make generator to yield a slice for each window yourself:

```
def window(length, size=2, start=0):
    while start + size <= length:
        yield slice(start, start + size)
        start += 1
```

and then loop through it..

```
In [144]: from pandas import DataFrame
     ...: import numpy as np
     ...: 
     ...: df = DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(2,5).T, columns=['a','b'])
     ...: 
     ...: df.iloc[0,1] = -1       #still perfect with ranked correlation, but not with pearson's r
     ...: 
     ...: for w in window(len(df), size=3):
     ...:     df_win = df.iloc[w,:]
     ...:     spearman = df_win['a'].rank().corr(df_win['b'].rank())
     ...:     pearson  = df_win['a'].corr(df_win['b'])
     ...:     print w.start, spearman, pearson
     ...:     
0 1.0 0.917662935482
1 1.0 1.0
2 1.0 1.0
```